# Mongo insert and update query performs slow. Why?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a server which consistently insert and update the data in MongoDb collections.

I have 3 collections : handTab, video, handHistory.

When the no of documents in those collection reaches 40000, 40000, 80000 respectively, then the insert and update and findAndModify command's performance degrades.

In the mongo Compass I have seen that these query are the slowest operations.
Also, the CPU utilization on production server goes upto 100%.

This leads to the server connection timeout of my game-server API.

I have database on a machine and game-server running on other machine, Why the CPU utilization of database machine reaches 100% after the data size become large in collections, i have same number of mongo operations previously as well as now?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have database on a machine and game-server running on other machine, Why the CPU utilization of database machine reaches 100% after the data size become large in collections, i have same number of mongo operations executing previously as well as now? @NeilLunn

Comment: You are asking for a solution to a problem without providing the necessary means for anyone to reproduce it. Without such emprical data we cannot tell if there is a problem with what you are doing or if it's simply a matter of underspeced hardware, and which in the latter case is **not a programming problem** and basically off-topic for a question on this site. Basically to be **on-topic** your question here **must** provide a sample of code that reproduces the issue. Otherwise, your question belongs on https://dba.stackexchange.com, but is also really **too broad** for there as well.

Comment: Bottom line is you want your database diagnosed without giving anyone the means to "log in" and diagnose the problem. And that makes it not a viable question for this site.